# Scrapy Spider runs but o pages crawled

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to web scraping and am trying to run a simple spider to collect name, brand, and price information from a website selling mountain bikes.  I am trying to build and run a spider all in on script as i think this is simpler for someone at my level.  The spider runs but resulting .csv file is empty.  The message in the terminal after attempting to run the spider lets you know that `INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)`.  I am unsure of why this spider wont crawl or collect any information from the site.

Ive tested the Urls I have in my code, i've tested the css locators identifying the info I want to pull from the sites html (also tried using xpath instead without luck), and Ive tried a few different ways of writing my loop used to scrap all pages of the site. All with no success.

My only remaining ideas are that there is some syntax error in the beginning of my code causing the spider to malfunction or there is some issue with my loop that attempts to crawl all subsequent pages, not only the first. Also, this site has infinite scrolling. could this be an issue?

What am i doing wrong?!?!?!

All code/error messages/ info included below

- the code:

```
import scrapy
import requests
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class BikeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name='mountianbikespider'
    
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request('https://www.incycle.com/pages/search-results-page?collection=mountain-bikes&page=1')
        
    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.css('li.snize-product-in-stock')
        for item in products:      
            yield {
                'name' : item.css('span.snistrong textze-title::text').extract(),
                'description' : item.css('span.snize-description::text').extract(),
                'price' : item.css('span.snize-price::text').extract()    
            }
            
#this loop will make the spider not only crawl the first page of bikes, but also continue to all pages afterwards, collection the same info as on page 1
# to do this you must change the url to include page={x} in the place of page=1
        for x in range(2,10):
            yield(scrapy.Request(f'https://www.incycle.com/pages/search-results-page?collection=mountain-bikes&page={x}', callback=self.parse))
        
#this is what saves the data in a seperate place (in this case a csv namesbikes.csv)
process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    "FEEDS":{"bikes.csv":{"format": "csv"}} 
})    

#this is what actually runs the spider
process.crawl(BikeSpider)
process.start()
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: What error is scray displaying? Do you get a 403, etc? Can you post scrapy error trace?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your xpath is wrong.
2. Even if it was right the page is loaded with JavaScript so it wouldn't work.
3. Not really a mistake - but you can replace the pagination loop with `start_urls = [f'https://www.incycle.com/pages/search-results-page?collection=mountain-bikes&page={i}' for i in range(1, 10)]` in the beginning of the class, it looks much nicer.

In order to scrape the contents of the page you can either get it from the `script` (I haven't tried to because it's harder), or get it from the API:

```py
import scrapy
import logging


class BikeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'mountianbikespider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.incycle.com/pages/search-results-page?collection=mountain-bikes&page=1']
    headers = {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "DNT": "1",
        "Host": "searchserverapi.com",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Referer": "https://www.incycle.com/",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "script",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "no-cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
        "Sec-GPC": "1",
        "TE": "trailers",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
    }
    custom_settings = {'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.6}
    API_key = ''
    start_index = 0
    max_results = 50
    total_pages_to_scrape = 3

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.start_urls[0], callback=self.get_API_key)

    def get_API_key(self, response):
        API_key = response.xpath('//script[contains(text(), "searchserverapi")]/text()').re_first(r'a=(.+?)\\')
        if not API_key:
            self.log('Could not find the API key', logging.ERROR)
            return

        self.API_key = API_key
        url = f'https://searchserverapi.com/getresults?api_key={self.API_key}&q=&sortBy=created&sortOrder=desc&startIndex={self.start_index}&maxResults={self.max_results}&items=true&pages=true&categories=true&suggestions=true&queryCorrection=true&suggestionsMaxResults=3&pageStartIndex=0&pagesMaxResults=20&categoryStartIndex=0&categoriesMaxResults=20&facets=true&facetsShowUnavailableOptions=false&ResultsTitleStrings=2&ResultsDescriptionStrings=2&collection=mountain-bikes&action=moreResults&output=jsonp'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, headers=self.headers)

    def parse(self, response):
        json_data = response.json()

        for item in json_data['items']:
            yield {
                'name': item['title'],
                'description': item['description'],
                'price': item['price']
            }

        # next page
        self.start_index += self.max_results
        if self.start_index > self.total_pages_to_scrape*self.max_results:
            self.log('Finished scraping')
            return

        url = f'https://searchserverapi.com/getresults?api_key={self.API_key}&q=&sortBy=created&sortOrder=desc&startIndex={self.start_index}&maxResults={self.max_results}&items=true&pages=true&categories=true&suggestions=true&queryCorrection=true&suggestionsMaxResults=3&pageStartIndex=0&pagesMaxResults=20&categoryStartIndex=0&categoriesMaxResults=20&facets=true&facetsShowUnavailableOptions=false&ResultsTitleStrings=2&ResultsDescriptionStrings=2&collection=mountain-bikes&action=moreResults&output=jsonp'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, headers=self.headers)
```

If you want to get other products you need to change `collection` in the url to other value, you may want to create a variable for convenience.